# Clearable input removes text from input but deosnot make control invalid

Tags: javascript

I have a simple angular2 form where i have setup clear icon on input which clears the data in input when clicked on it... The problem is when i click on the icon it removes data from but it doesnot make the control invalid...I have the code implemented in this demo http://plnkr.co/edit/O6WhKkagS1zv9LaWvRSt?p=preview
This is how i am clearing the text from the input box when data is entered and user clicks on clear icon

```
    function tog(v) { return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'; }
$(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
    $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
}).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {
    $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 18 < e.clientX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
}).on('touchstart click', '.onX', function (ev) {
     ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).focus();
    $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
});
```

Somebody please help me how to make the control invalid if the input is required 
type

Comment: How is this related to Angular2?

Comment: Sorry the issue is not related to angular 2 , i thought the function which i wrote to clear the text should know whether the control is required or not? In Microsoft edge browser there is a clear icon which browser supports...That clear icon actually makes the control invalid after clicking on icon...I want to implement in that way...Is there any approach to do that